# Clarification needed for two exercises on Ideals in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I have some questions for the following two exercises:

1. Find a ring $R$ with unit element in which there exists elements $s_1$, $s_2$ such that $\{s_1 x_1 + s_2 x_2\mid x_1, x_2 \in R\}$ is not an ideal of R
2. Find an ideal $J$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\{0\}\neq J \neq \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and for any $ 0 \leq k \in \mathbb{Z}$ $J \neq \{a_{n}x^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}x + a_{0}\mid a_{0} = 0 = a_{1} = \cdots = a_{k}\}$

For problem (1), would the ring $R$ of the set of quaternion suffice?
for problem (2), I am a bit confused what the conditions $J$ needs to satisfied.  I am guessing $J$ could be $\{a_{n}x^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}x + a_{0}\mid a_{i} \neq 0, a_{0} = 0 = a_{1}= \cdots = a_{i-1} = a_{i+1} = \cdots = a_{k}\}$. or $J$ could also be $\{a_{n}x^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}x + a_{0}\mid a_{k+1} = 0 = a_{k+2} = \cdots = a_{n}\}$
I am not sure if my interpretation of the question is correct.  If someone can let me know, it would be much appreciated it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For (1), the quaternions will not work. For (2), neither of those two sets is an ideal.

Comment: @DonAntonio This is not true -- $s_1 R + s_2 R$ is always a right ideal, but not always a two-sided ideal. For example, take your favorite simple ring which is not a division algebra (trying to be vague here). It probably has a principal right ideal which is not a two-sided ideal.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk for (1) I assume if we have non commutativity, then it should not be an ideal.  For (2) if what I suggested doesn't work, then I am not certain how to satisfied the conditions for what $J$ is suppose to be.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Excellent point. I assumed implictly that $\;R\;$ is commutative, a mistake. Deleting comment.

Comment: @DonAntonio for both (1) and (2), the definition of ideal used in the text is what is usually stated in a beginning abstract algebra text of an ideal for a ring have two sided ideals.

Comment: @SethMai The issue is that the quaternions are a division algebra: $\{s_1 x_1 : x_1 \in R\}$ will be either $\{0\}$ or $R$. You can use this to prove that $\{s_1 x_1 + s_2 x_2 : s_1, s_2 \in R\}$ will be either $0$ or $R$, hence always an ideal.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk for (1) what about the ring of 2 by 2 matrices with entries only in $\mathbb{Z}$?  I don't know what a division algebra is.  Rather I have not learn it.  I was hoping for something simple and familiar.  For (2) can you explain to me what $J$ is suppose to be. It seems like there is a lot of conditions there being needed to satisfied at once. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ will work for (1). You'll still need to find the elements $s_1, s_2$! $J$ is supposed to be an ideal which is not of a particular form. Here's how to find such a thing, in general: think of an ideal (any ideal), and then check if it is of the form $\{a_{n}x^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}x + a_{0}\mid a_{0} = 0 = a_{1} = \cdots = a_{k}\}$. If not, you're done! If it is of that form, think of another ideal and repeat.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk for (2) am I to interpret the conditions that any ideals I come up with involving polynomials, all the coefficients can not simultaneously all be zero?  Is my understanding correct?